# FaceTime audio is garbled

Tags: iphone, facetime

Whenever my wife FaceTimes our son in the US (using her iPhone6) the sound is garbled.

We can see and hear him OK, but whenever she speaks, the sound is very loud and distorted, and sometimes with a delay (or echo.)

When we FaceTime family in Australia, everything seems OK.

The connection is via our WiFi modem.

Anyone have any idea WHY, and if this can be fixed?

Comment: • What device is your son using in the US? • When you make phone calls (not FaceTime calls) is the audio normal? • If you FaceTime _without_ video, is the audio normal? • Have you tried, as a test, other video chat apps such as Skype, Google Meet or Zoom?

Comment: Table for 4 please :)